# Is there a way to dynamically change the title of embedded svg object?

Tags: html, svg, dynamic, title, html-object

By 'embedded svg object', I mean an html `<object>` tag that is an svg file, such as this:

```
<object id="svgobject" 
data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg"
type="image/svg+xml" title="I want to see this title!"></object>
```

example fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/d8jx3ru7/

It appears that even though `<object>` supports the title attribute, if it is an SVG image then it has no effect.

I can put a static title in the SVG file, but what if the title needs to be determined dynamically?  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's no real way to do that cross-domain. If you were on the same domain you could reach into the SVG with javascript and change its title dynamically.

Comment: _It appears that even though <object> supports the title attribute, if it is an SVG image then it has no effect_  I don't understand, what effect you wish to create with the title attribute? _but what if the title needs to be determined dynamically?_ Is this a seperate question?

Comment: Normally when an `<object>` with a title is hovered, it displays a tooltip.  That's the effect I'm trying to create.  No, the other question is not separate.  I'm clarifying that putting a title in the SVG file will not work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could

```
$("#svgobject").attr('title', 'Whatever you want');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you try that to check it works when the image is SVG (which is the point of the quesion).